# How to display and update the same image across multiple pages?

Tags: html, image

Is there a good way to display the same image on multiple pages using HTML or a third party tool? I'd like to display the same image on multiple blog posts and easily update all of them from a single location whenever I want, based on changing promotions. I know there has to be a simple solution for this but have not been able to think of one.

Comment: I would create a div like `<div class="image-wrapper">` and use CSS background: url` property to display that image. I would call that div on any page which would call the `background:url` property. If you needed to update the image all you would have to do is change the image name in the css and it'll update for all those divs across all page as long as you had that css document linked with those pages in an include or hardcoded.

Comment: Don't understand that question. Just use the same image location on each page... If you want to avoid caching issues add a timestamp to the image url like src="myImage.jpg?<timestamp>".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your question you've only tagged HTML which is a static language. From my experience you'll need to either use a more dynamic language like PHP or jQuery to accomplish something like this.

For example in PHP you could do

```
<?php 
$changing_image = "path-to-image/image.png";
?>
```

Use Php variable in HTML

```
<img class="my_image" src="<?=$changing_image;?>" title="image">
```

In jQuery you could attach a class to `img` and do

```
$(".my_image").attr("src","other_image.png");
```

with CSS you could use the background-property by wrapping the images with a `div` and do

**html**

```
<div class="images"></div>
```

**css**

```
.images {
   width: 100%;
    height: 400px;
    background-image: url('img.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    }
```